# IReport and jasper report mystery

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am using a very old iReport 0.5 and a very old Jasper report. The project has been dormant for number of years.

I am having to make a change to an existing jrxml. I have done this successfully to many of the other existing ones. One is giving me problems.

So many of the jrxml files, I open it in iReport and change a control name from TextField12 to TextField121111 and I save the file. When I diff the old and the version, I see the one line change showing the name change.

The problematic jrxml, I do the same simple edit change and when I do a diff, there is a ton of changes. So who cares you ask. The problematic jrxml after the modification, always returns no data for my report, the query is correct when I run it interactively in my database.

How do I go about finding why this one report never returns any data for the report to display?

Thoughts on this?

Thanks

Comment: May be this problematic jrxml was created with the another iReport. Or even it was manually edited. You can simplify this report step by step until it begins to show data.

Answer (score 0):

this block, in full, was never written back to the newly saved file...

```
<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[ 
 ( $P{ReturnedValuesMap}.put("REPORT_COUNT", $V{sum_hits}.longValue()<=0 ?        
    $P{ReturnedValuesMap}.get("REPORT_COUNT") : $V{REPORT_COUNT} ) == null )?
   Boolean.FALSE:Boolean.FALSE

]]> </printWhenExpression> </reportElement> 
<graphicElement stretchType="NoStretch" pen="Thin" fill="Solid" />
```

problem solved when I manually add that back to the jrxml. Got to this after every save operation.